# Hibernate does not delete entries from removed objects in collection

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have two collections, `groups` and `permissions`. The first collection works well and removes the entries which got removed from the collection. But the `permissions` collection does not do what it should. I always remove entries from the collection but the changes won't be updated in the DB.

```java
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "user_groups")
    private List<Group> groups = new ArrayList<Group>();

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "user")
    @OrderBy("name ASC")
    private List<UserPermission> permissions = new ArrayList<UserPermission>();
```

The same code is used to save the Entity containing these two lists and equal code to remove the entries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use the `orphanRemoval = true`  the  orphan-removal allows you to remove the Child entity whenever it’s no longer referenced by its Parent:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "user", orphanRemoval = true)
    @OrderBy("name ASC")
    private List<UserPermission> permissions;
```